# How to insert into Sqlite DB even app killed from recent history?

Tags: android, sqlite

May be my question title won't describe my actual problem. I will try to explain my problem in detail.

1. I am writing 'XXX' App inside I am using 'YYY' android library project.
2. 'YYY' android library project will provides different call backs in one of the call back i will receive 'abc' object.
3. Now I am processing the object and storing SQlite DB as per my requirement.

This entire process works perfectly if my app is running(fore ground / recent app history). But my requirement it should work even app is not running.

Can any one give suggestions how can i achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Sample code snippet :

```
public class XXX AppCompatActivity implements YYYClass.SomeListener{

    onCreate(){...}
    .
    .
    .

    @Override
    public Object customCallback1(Object abc){

        //Database insertion happen here  

       //this part is working only app is in foreground / background(app recent history) 

       //I know that, this DB insertion won't work once the app got killed because this I am not doing any service.

      // If I want send this object to service class how can pass(I want
this should happen even app killed)


         return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Create a service, https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

Comment: I have done the same manner, but as i said "YYY" library is providing the 'abc' object. how can pass this object to service for SQlite insertion?. this should happen even app killed.

Comment: I'd recommend moving the code to handle using the library, and dealing with the callback to the service if possible. You can then send a local broadcast if the app is running in the foreground so it can update the UI

Comment: No It's an 3rd party library i can't  modify it we should use as it is. any other possibilities. And while app running in the foreground i don't have update issues. But i want the same  behavior even app killed.

Comment: Using a Service to start on a specific intent should do it. I can't remember exactly how I do it, but this is how I created an SMS app. The service start on sms reception and save it into the database. Your library should send an intent or a broadcast.

Comment: Why would someone even respond to such a badly formatted question?

Comment: @AxeIH: here the problem is library will give only callbacks. No modifications in that. I have tried all possible ways. But I checking with the people if any one come across with this kind of situation.

Comment: @Abdul : At present I searching only for the solution. not expecting any code base, That's why I have just mentioned what I want and the problem. If you not understand the problem, Plz let me know i can explain u in detail. In that you will be having better understanding. Thanks

Comment: @Gopi_Krish I was talking about the formatting of code in your question, not the clarity of it. Kindly format it properly.